# Accessing JSON object in xcode

Tags: ios, json, facebook, dictionary

This is a piece of the json file:

```
    {
   "title": "Facebook Wall",
   "link": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/",
   "self": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/feeds...format=json",
   "updated": "2013-10-31T05:18:14-07:00",
   "icon": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com.ico",
   "entries": [
      {
         "title": "  &quot;My mate Jamie Jamie Oliver stopped by for breakfast this mornin...",
         "id": "00c16...c18e678b9fc730e200",
         "alternate": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/photo.php?...1253688113063.464992.90824638062&type=1",
         "categories":...
```

I want to get the items from "entries". I tried making a dictionary and then making an NSData from object for key "entries" and converting it into another dictionary, but it failed to produce any result. Any ideas, tips or solutions are welcome.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"entries" is not a dictionnary, but an array. Try to parse it as an array first.

Comment: I actually gave up on trying to solve it like this and used json framework and it worked on the first try. And it was a dictionary, at least json framework allowed me to make a dictionary.